# Command-line tool to check JavaScript file ECMAScript version

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static-analysis

I'm working on a large (very large) project with tons of JavaScript files that are constantly being modified by different teams in different locations around the world. Some devs have used ES6 syntax which we need to find because some parts of our code have to run in browsers that don't support ES6 syntax.

We have been asked to check all our code to make sure that we haven't inadvertently used any ES6 syntax and I was wondering what would be the best way to check lots of JavaScript files in lots of sub-folders?

Other similar questions I've found on SO have answers saying to use JSLint or similar...this is great for checking as you go along, but there are too many files to do manually.

Comment: Linters (e.g. [eslint](https://eslint.org/)) have command line interfaces. You can just run it over the code base in powershell. Depending on how you're doing CI/CD it could be made a pre-deploy condition of your pipeline. Speaking of pipelines, a better solution to your problem is to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: "browsers that don't support ES6 syntax" that's only Internet Explorer. Microsoft themselves are [officially killing IE](https://www.forbes.com/sites/carlypage/2021/05/20/microsoft-is-finally-killing-off-internet-explorerin-2022/). You can stop supporting it now.

Comment: @JeremyThille...LOL. I was trying to be kind to IE by not mentioning it directly. We will stop supporting it imminently but in the meantime, we still have the pain of keeping it going for a little while longer.

Comment: @JaredSmith, great suggestion about using Babel, but that decision is above my pay grade :-D. I'll look into the command line interface of eslint that you've mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @oak that's worth lobbying for but on a more meta note, and I realize this isn't necessarily anything that you personally can do much about but...well, there are a *lot* of red flags in your question. Red flags like 1. your teams are apparently not empowered to choose to use industry best-practice tools even if doing so doesn't impact other teams #2 linters and compilers are not already part of your build pipeline #3 you do have an automated build pipeline, right? #4 your devs should have already told you all of this with you having to ask us #5 you should have realized everything in this...

Comment: ...[cont] comment without me telling you and maybe mentioned some of it in the question (and again, you may know all this already and just not thought it worth mentioning [it's worth mentioning]). I work for a decent-sized org with~200 developers. The main codebase I work on has about 10 different teams spread out across North America and Europe contributing to it. There is *no way on Earth* we could do that without modern tools and processes without it turning into the proverbial [big ball of mud](https://wiki.c2.com/?BigBallOfMud).

Comment: I also realize I should specify, glancing at your profile I'm assuming that you are in some sort of engineering management or senior technologist role, but your comment about stuff being way above your pay grade is making me re-think that. Again, sorry if this is old hat to you I'm not trying to rub salt in the wound.

Answer (score 3):

Easy done [ES Check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-check)

#### Side Note

> Some devs have used ES6 syntax which we need to find because some parts of our code have to run in browsers that don't support ES6 syntax.

Rather than finding ES6 code to replace it with ES5 (which is a waste of resources) you should simply take your codebase and transpile it to ES5 with a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Your devs keep working with whatever EcmaScript version they prefer and you get ES5 code at the end of the day.

Comment: I agree with your side note but we have coding standards that the Devs need to adhere to and that includes, for now, not using ES6 syntax. For the most part, they do their best, but some instances still sneak in. We just need to find those few instances.

Comment: @oak Then I hope ES Check works for you ;)